# Error Compiling simple program Error LNK2019

Tags: c++

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl findlowest(int,int,int,int,int)" (?findlowest@@YAHHHHHH@Z) referenced in function _main  G:\C++\Chapter 6\Lowest Score drop\Lowest Score drop\Source.obj Lowest Score drop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//Function prototypes
void getscore(int &score);
int findlowest(int, int, int, int, int);
void calcAverage(int, int, int, int, int, int);

int lowest = 0;

int main()
{
int score1, score2, score3, score4, score5;

getscore(score1); // return 1st score
getscore(score2); // return 2nd score
getscore(score3); // return 3rd score
getscore(score4); //return 4th score
getscore(score5); //return 5th score


lowest = findlowest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);

calcAverage(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, lowest);

return 0;
}

void getscore(int &score)
{
for (int count = 1; count <= 5; count++)
{
    cout << "Please enter test score for test " << count << ": ";
    cin >> score;
}
}

int findLowest(int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5)
{
int calclowest = score1;
{
    if (score2 < score1)
        calclowest = score2;
    else if (score3 < score2)
        calclowest = score3;
    else if (score4 < score3)
        calclowest = score4;
    else if (score5 < score4)
        calclowest = score5;
}
cout << "The lowest test score is " << calclowest << endl;
return calclowest;  
}

void calcAverage(int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5, int lowest)
{
int average;
average = ((score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5) - lowest)/4;
cout << "The average of the 4 highest scores is " << average << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typographical error when you wrote  the definition of the function `findlowest`.

```
int findLowest(int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5)
```

The `l` in `findLowest` is in upper case where as the forward declaration and the function call has the `l` in lower case.

```
int findlowest(int, int, int, int, int);
lowest = findlowest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
```

Comment: Such a simple error but yet seemed to cause me so many problems. Thank you for the help. Always helps to just get a second pair of eyes on things.

Answer (score 0):

As Abhijit correctly points out, this is caused by a typo. To further elaborate, you have declared a function called `findlowest` which takes 5 `int`: its signature is aptly `int findlowest(int, int, int, int, int)`. You have then tried to call that function in your `main`. This compiles correctly because the compiler is aware of a declaration of that function and that's all it needs; however, when your program tries to link it needs a definition of the function `int findlowest(int, int, int, int, int)` (since you are calling it) but it cannot find a definition, which is what the linker error is saying. `int findLowest` is a new declaration and definition of a function which is not used.